# iptables: block ports but not log all ports

Tags: logging, redhat, iptables

I have all ports blocked in my iptables except those I specifically want open. However, in my iptables.log file I have dozens of requests coming in using ports 137,138,139 because our corporate network keeps thinking our box may be a windows box. Unfortunately, I can't prevent this from happening, so the next option is to either open the ports, or prevent the logs being written.

Is it possible to prevent iptables.log from being written for specific ports, but still log all other blocked ports? Or do I need to disable iptables.log completely?

this is in my /etc/rsyslog.conf file

```
:msg, startswith, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
:msg, regex, "^\[ *[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\] iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

RedHat 6.5

Output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       98  6744 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2      385 51303 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
3     2102  166K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
5      119 18187 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
8        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:3306 state ESTABLISHED
9       70  3104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       10./16        0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 1556,10082,10102,13720,13724,13782 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 1556,10082,10102,13720,13724,13782 state ESTABLISHED
11     115 18624 LOGGING    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 887 packets, 53828 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       98  6744 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2      418 36439 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
3     1801  230K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
5      193 21974 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:3306 state ESTABLISHED
8        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
9       50  4570 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport sports 1556,10082,10102,13720,13724,13782 state ESTABLISHED
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    10./16        0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 1556,10082,10102,13720,13724,13782 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       94 16986 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix `iptables: '
2      115 18624 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: It is possible. What is the output of `sudo iptables -nvL --line-numbers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following rules:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 11 -p udp -i eth0 --dport 139 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT 11 -p udp -i eth0 --dport 138 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT 11 -p udp -i eth0 --dport 137 -j DROP
```

These will cause `iptables` to drop the specified packets before they reach the logging rule. In particular, it adds the `DROP` action as action number 11 (before the logging action which is currently number 11), in the `INPUT` chain of the `filter` table.

Note that you might have to restart `iptables`, as follows:

```
sudo service iptables restart
```

Comment: I thought that having the policies set to DROP by default would not require the first 3 lines that you wrote. Isn't that duplicating what I already have done?

Comment: The default policy kicks in only when no matched rule is found. In your case, a matched rule is found in the `LOGGING` chain, and the policy is never enforced. The second rule of the `LOGGING` chain specifies that all packets who have reached it are to be dropped. The rule preceding that specifies that they should also be logged. In order to avoid their logging, I've added these 3 rules that drop them before they get an opportunity to be logged. All other ports are still logged, just like before, per your request.

Comment: Ok great info. I will try it and report back!